# Why do subsequent reads of a multi-gigabyte file run faster?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, cache, io

I have some algorithm test software running on a Windows 7 machine which, when run the first time on any given data file, runs ~3-5x slower than on subsequent runs. Our algorithm simply reads the file a few hundred bytes at a time and writes one result back for every ~50 reads operations.

Is there some inherent caching somewhere in Windows (seems unlikely with a 3GB file?) or something else? Is there any way I can speed up that first run?

Comment: Yes, Windows does have a cache that could be responsible for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there any way to disable it temporarily for specific files or generally to check that's what we're seeing?

Comment: Well, according to the MSDN you can disable caching for a certain file with the flag `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` in the `CreateFile` call. If you can't change the code, you'll probably have to resort to another approach; you could try to empty the cache between runs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing

Comment: If you post that lot as an answer Martin, I'll accept it. I was able to flush the file from the cache using the software in the link you provided and consequently produce consistent benchmark results :)

Comment: I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some inherent caching somewhere in Windows (seems unlikely with a 3GB file?)

Yes, [Windows does have a cache that could be responsible for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx).

According to the linked MSDN article you can disable caching for a certain file with the flag FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING in the CreateFile call. If you can't change the code, you can instead use the [SysInternals RAMMap app](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) to reset the cache between benchmark runs.

[See this related posting on SO for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing).